# How list items from table with wildcard in sqlite using c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, wildcard, sql-like

How can I get elements from table using wildcard?

I've made code something like that.
What is wron here? Is it safe if I put this into loop ?

```
private void Pokaz()
    {
        String sql = "SELECT [element] FROM [table] LIKE @Word";
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Temp2\dictionary.s3db");
        connection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", "%" + "dog" + "%");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

I changed to `String sql = "SELECT [element] FROM [table] where [element] LIKE \'@Word\'";`
 But now I get empty result.

---

I tried also this method. Fixed and works. Still above not.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Temp2\dictionary.s3db";
        string sql = "SELECT [element] FROM [table] where [element] LIKE  \'%dog%\' ";

        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SQLiteDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(rd[0].ToString());
                }       

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
String insSQL = "SELECT [element] FROM [table] like @Word"; //% search with prefix and postfix

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insSQL);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", "%" + "dog" + "%");
```

?